# Fabricjs: Load svg from local folder

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I need to load `1.svg` from a local folder. In the following code, when I replace `fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg"` with `fabric.loadSVGFromURL("1.svg"`, the image no longer displays in canvas. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var group = [];
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg",function(objects,options) {
            var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
            loadedObjects.set({
                left: 100,
                top: 100,
                width:175,
                height:175
            });
            canvas.add(loadedObjects);
            canvas.renderAll();
        },function(item, object) {
                object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
        });
    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="900"></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's security model doesn't allow it. You can run with the command line option --allow-file-access-from-files to override this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this file hosted on a server ? If its not, once you host the html file in a server it will display the svg image. The svg file need to be in the same folder under the website where you place the html file.